# Invalid class property declaration for json mapping

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, mailgun

I have below `json` received from `mailgun API`.

```
{
  "items": [{
    "delivery-status": {
      "message": null,
      "code": 605,
      "description": "Not delivering to previously bounced address",
      "session-seconds": 0
    },
    "event": "failed",
    "log-level": "error",
    "recipient": "test@test.com"
  },
  {
      //some other properties of above types
  }]
}
```

Now I was trying to create a class structure for above `json` to auto-map the properties after `deserializing`.

```
public class test
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string recipient { get; set; }
    public string @event { get; set; }
    public DeliveryStatus delivery_status { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryStatus
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I `deserialize` and try to map the properties.

```
var resp = client.Execute(request);
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var content = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(resp.Content);
test testContent = (test)json.Deserialize(resp.Content, typeof(test));
var eventType = testContent.items[0].@event;
var desc = testContent.items[0].delivery_status.description; //stays null
```

Now in the above class `Item`, `recipient` and `@event` gets mapped properly and since it was a `keyword` I was suppose to use preceding `@` character and it works well. But the `delivery-status` property from `json`, does not get mapped with `delevery_status` property in `class DeliveryStatus`. I have tried creating it as `deliveryStatus` or `@deliver-status`. The earlier on doesn't map again and the later one throws compile time exception. Is there anyway these things can be handled, like declaring a property with `-` in between? I cannot change `response json` as it is not getting generated from my end. Hoping for some help.

**Update**

Changed the class as below referring **[`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564441/2065039)**, but did not help. Its `null` again.

```
public class Item
{
    public string @event { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "delivery-status")]
    public DeliveryStatus deliveryStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is using `Json.NET` (which can handle this) rather than the default `JavaScriptSerializer` an option?

Comment: `DeliveryStatus` class has few properties instead of one. There are: message, code , description, session-seconds.

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke.. Please let me know how I can achieve it with `Json.NET`?

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` can also be used as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753113/how-to-deserialize-a-property-with-a-dash-in-its-name-with-newtonsoft-jso)

Comment: @MaciejLos.. Yea agreed.. But in my case, its not necessary..

Comment: Isn't better to define these fields and tell to deserializer to ignore them?

Comment: For `Json.NET`, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563702/model-to-match-this-json-for-deserialization-field-names-with-dashes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. I tried with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "delivery-status")]` but did not help. do I need to deserialize in a separate way?

Comment: That should work if you change the property name to (say) `DeliveryStatus`

Comment: @MaciejLos.. I believe, it does automatically if am not wrong..

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated question.. Did not work either.. Is deserializing way proper in my case?

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Any help here?

Comment: I assume you did set the serializer to use Json.NET. Cant see any reason why it would not work, but I can't test it at the moment (will check over the weekend if you have not resolved it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sure.. Let me know if I can provide you `json` sample through any other medium.. In the mean time am opting with `dynamic` declaration, even though I feel its not proper..

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right (of course), it does work. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue is at your end, but at least it works if you use this code. Make sure to include a recent version of Newtonsoft.Json in your project and you should be fine.

```
public class DeliveryStatus
{
    public object message { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("session-seconds")]
    public int session_seconds { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("delivery-status")]
    public DeliveryStatus delivery_status { get; set; }
    public string @event { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("log-level")]
    public string log_level { get; set; }
    public string recipient { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string json = @"{
  ""items"": [{
    ""delivery-status"": {
                ""message"": null,
      ""code"": 605,
      ""description"": ""Not delivering to previously bounced address"",
      ""session-seconds"": 0
    },
    ""event"": ""failed"",
    ""log-level"": ""error"",
    ""recipient"": ""test@test.com""
  }]
}";

    RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what was wrong, but I changed this line `(test)json.Deserialize(resp.Content, typeof(test));` to `test r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test>(resp.Content);` and yes now it works.. So basically, the `deserialization` was  not happening properly with `json.Deserialize`?

Comment: I guess you were trying to mix Microsoft's `JavaScriptSerializer` with JSON.NET's `JsonProperty` attributes. That won't work.

Comment: Yea.. That's the problem may be.. Anyways.. Nice to know the solution.. Thanks much and thank you @StephenMuecke.. Finally its resolved.. :)